# How to pass variable from one function to another function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, azure-language-understanding

I want to pass the `topic_to_learn` variable to the second function and use it in the second function for something else.

```javascript
    function (session, args, next) {
        var topic_to_learn = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'topic_to_learn');
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Sure, can you please also tell me about your goals or anything you want to achieve after learning about this topic?');
    },
    function (session, results, next) {
        var learning_goals = results.response;
        session.send('Got it, let me think...', session.message.text);
        session.send('Voila! These are the articles related to ' + topic_to_learn, session.message.text);
    },
```

Comment: Please provide the full code or at least a [mcve]. Those two function expressions with commas in between are a syntax error when standing alone. Are they calling each other? It's totally unclear how they are used.

Comment: thanks so much, all of your answers inspired me and I found the way to do it, so much thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use an above-scoped variable, available to both the functions.

```
   var topic_to_learn;

    function (session, args, next) {
        topic_to_learn = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'topic_to_learn');
        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Sure, can you please also tell me about your goals or anything you want to achieve after learning about this topic?');
    };

    function (session, results, next) {
        var learning_goals = results.response;
        session.send('Got it, let me think...', session.message.text);
        session.send('Voila! These are the articles related to ' + topic_to_learn, session.message.text);
    },
```

Comment: thanks so much...i tried too but it fails, it seems that i cannot write that way as the two functions seem to be stored in another function..

Comment: .matches('get_learning_plan', [

        function (session, args, next) {
            ...

Comment: best way would be to create a module for all 3 functions and serially require them in the subsequent function. This way you can access the variables inside the function as if they were object properties (func1.topic_to_learn)

Comment: hey man, i am using another library thats why my code seems a bit strange, but your answer definitely inspired me, i just found another way to solve it, so much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.matches('get_learning_plan', [

        function (session, args, next) {
            var topic_to_learn = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'topic_to_learn');
            builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Sure, can you please also tell me about your goals or anything you want to achieve after learning about this topic?');
        },
        function (session, results, next) {
            var learning_goals = results.response;
            session.send('Got it, let me think...', session.message.text);
            session.send('Voila! These are the articles related to ' + topic_to_learn, session.message.text);
        },
```

Comment: Is this an answer?